# \ifdefstring with logical operator, is it possible?

Tags: etoolbox

```
        \ifdefstring{command}{str1 OR str2}{yes}{no}
```

something like above needs to be achieved. is it possible to use logical operator for the string part of \ifdefstring ?

package : `etoolbox`

command = string type

I added `etoolbox` to this project and used `\ifdefstring`
source : https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV

Comment: Where does `\ifdefstring` come from? Please post a full document code, not just fragments only

Comment: You have a macro, say `\foo` that may expand to a string and you wish that `\ifdefstring{\foo}{str1||str2}{yes}{no}` returns `yes` if `\foo` is defined and expands to `str1` or `str2` and `no` otherwise?

Comment: @egreg yes. exactly.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer , i dont think it has anything to do with the code. its a simple feature of etoolbox package. Still i have added the repository link.  I have made modifications to that.

Comment: @ronpatel: I don't see a link. Your question is still unclear to me

Answer (score 1):

You can build a boolean expression:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifdefstringor}[2]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\ifboolexpr{
      test {\noexpand\ifdefstring{\noexpand#1}{\@firstoftwo#2}}
      or
      test {\noexpand\ifdefstring{\noexpand#1}{\@secondoftwo#2}}
    }%
  }\x
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\fooA}{str1}
\newcommand{\fooB}{str2}
\newcommand{\fooC}{str3}

\begin{document}

\ifdefstringor{\fooA}{{str1}{str2}}{yes}{no}

\ifdefstringor{\fooB}{{str1}{str2}}{yes}{no}

\ifdefstringor{\fooC}{{str1}{str2}}{yes}{no}

\ifdefstringor{\fooD}{{str1}{str2}}{yes}{no}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: so i can safely assume etool `\ifdefstring` does not allow logical operation on string, right ?

Comment: @ronpatel I see no direct support for it.

Comment: is there any other you can suggest. I dont want to create helper functions for menial tasks ?